# hibernate: get count of loaded elements

Tags: java, hibernate

Is it possible to get count of all loaded elements (separated by collections) by hibernate? For example, I have two classes Class1 and Class2, and I want to get count of loaded elements Class1 and elements Class2.

I want to implement monitoring of loaded elements by hibernate in my Spring app, for understanding of implementation quality.

Hibernate 5, Spring 5

Answer (score 0):

Session class has the:

> `SessionStatistics getStatistics()`
>
> Get the statistics for this session.

This interface has `getCollectionCount()` and `getCollectionKeys()` methods.

This will enable monitoring of the content of the current persistence context.